# Changing data in MS-SQL-Management Studio (SSMS) with BIT field named 'send' fails

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, alter-table

I do not understand why SMSS Table editor does not work with a table which contains a BIT data type field which is named 'send', e.g

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_fehler](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [send] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test_fehler] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_test_fehler_send]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [send]
```

Inserting rows are ok. Changing [name] with the table editor in existing rows fail with

[image: message from ssms]

If the column name is NOT 'send', it works fine. Very strange

Comment: If it fails in SSMS it will fail in ADODB, so that part is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name The [tag:ssms] tag is relevant to the question as the OP explains it's happening in the Table Editor UI. Not sure why you would tag this [tag:sql-update], there is no mention of the SQL `UPDATE` statement? - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63469145/3)

Comment: @Lankymart: because the error message reads "no row was updated"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That message is misleading but it doesn't relate to an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: When you updated the row, what did you put for the value of the `send` column? Also, is there a trigger on the table?

Comment: Quite frankly - just DON'T use SSMS editor to add, delete, or update rows. It has known issues. Just write the appropriate DML statements and execute them in a query window.

Comment: The send column was left unchanged and  there are no other triggers on the table. ADODB.Recordset problably uses same procedure as SSMS (as stated below) to update the record. So I will change it to a manual DML command in my application.
Thanks for clarification and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It is an error in SSMS! Use DML statements to do the update.

The error seems to center around the fact that "SEND" is a kind of reserved word in TSQL - it's not on the standard lists, but together with "RECEIVE" it is used for Service Broker.

SSMS seems to handle it in an inelegant way. You can see what happens if you open a SQL Server Profiler and catch the statements that SSMS tries to execute.

Here is what i caught in the profiler for an example where I have put in a row with name "a", and ID "1".

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE TOP (200) test_fehler SET name = @name WHERE (id = @Param1) AND (name = @Param2) AND (''send'' = @Param3)'
                 , N'@name nvarchar(1),@Param1 int,@Param2 nvarchar(1),@Param3 bit'
                 , @name = N'f'
                 , @Param1 = 1
                 , @Param2 = N'a'
                 , @Param3 = 0
```

As you can see SSMS "knows" that send is special, but uses a ' for escaping it, which is why you get the error code.

Now see what happens if I in stead use "update" for the column name. Column being a reserved word:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE TOP (200) test_fehler SET name = @name WHERE (id = @Param1) AND (name = @Param2) AND ([update] = @Param3)'
                 , N'@name nvarchar(1),@Param1 int,@Param2 nvarchar(1),@Param3 bit'
                 , @name = N'f'
                 , @Param1 = 1
                 , @Param2 = N'a'
                 , @Param3 = 0
```

Here the column name is escaped by [] and the operation succeeds!

You get the same error if you use "receive" for the column name:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE TOP (200) test_fehler SET name = @name WHERE (id = @Param1) AND (name = @Param2) AND (''receive'' = @Param3)'
                 , N'@name nvarchar(1),@Param1 int,@Param2 nvarchar(1),@Param3 bit'
                 , @name = N'f'
                 , @Param1 = 1
                 , @Param2 = N'a'
                 , @Param3 = 0
```

The answer is to change the column name, or use DML statements to update.